# How to detect if video is Landscape/portrait when fetched from PHAsset?

Tags: ios, swift, avasset, phasset

I am fetching videos from PHAsset so user can choose the video and import to perform edit. But user should be only able to select video with Landscape orientation, if user select portrait video, she/he would get alert message saying that its portrait video and hence can not import to edit.

One way to do this is creating AVAsset from URL of PHFetchResults, and then checking a preferedTransform, but that would be very costly operation to do right?

Is there a way to do this without creating AVasset?

Comment: I don't think it is as costly as you think.

Comment: hmm, i was thinking could I check imageOrientation of thumbnail to identify if video is portrait, this wont required to make avasset of video.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/PHAsset_Class/

> **var pixelWidth: Int { get }**
>
> **var pixelHeight: Int { get }**
>
> The width and height, in pixels, of the asset’s image or video data. (read-only)
>
> If the asset’s content has
> been edited, this property describes the size of the current version
> of the asset. Availability    iOS (8.0 and later)

```
if asset!.pixelHeight > asset!.pixelWidth {
 // will be portrait video or Image
}
```

**Available in iOS 8.0 and later.**

Comment: This doesn't tell you if it's left or right, though.