# Getting size (height and width) from PHAsset

Tags: ios, uicollectionviewlayout, phasset, phphotolibrary

Is there a way to get the height and width of the image from a `PHAsset` object.

I'm trying to make an image picker with a custom `UICollectionViewLayout` (Kind of like the main page of Pinterest app) I'v fetched all of the photos from the photo library into an array as `PHAsset` objects. But I need to get the size of the image from the `PHAsset` object for the delegate method `collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:`

Is there a fast way to achieve this?

Comment: Refer this link https://gist.github.com/MatthiasHoldorf/b4d0488641feb5d8ec55

Comment: DUPLICATE of [How to detect if video is Landscape/portrait when fetched from PHAsset?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37596555/3177007)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`PHAsset` has `pixelWidth` and `pixelHeight` properties.

Answer (score 1):

You can get them using this.

```
let imgheight = yourAsset.pixelHeight
let imgwidth = yourAsset.pixelWidth
```